# flutter firebase collection show in textfiled like dropdown menu

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, textfield

I have a collection in firebase, I want the documents in it to be displayed in the textfield when the textfield is clicked. how do i do it like dropdown menu?

Answer (score 1):

Just make a list out of all the data which you want to use :

```
QuerySnapshot feed = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(email)
        .get();
    dataList = [];
    for (var element in feed.docs) {
      dataList.add(element['title']);
    }
```

Once you get it in a form of list simply insert that list into the dropdown you desire :

```
          String dropDownValue = "Select Item"; //assign a variable to store the selection
          DropdownButton(
              value: dropDownValue,
               
              icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),   
               
              items: dataList.map((String items) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: items,
                  child: Text(items),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  dropdownvalue = newValue!;
                });
              },
            ),
```

For TextField you can use it with FutureBuilder while tapping into onTap method:

```
TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
FutureBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) { 
                  return Stack(
                    children: [TextField(
                      onTap: (){
                        setState(() {
                            showDropdown = true;
                        });
                      },
                      controller: textEditingController(),
                    ),
                     showDropdown ? DropdownButton(

                        value: dropDownValue,

                        icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),

                        items: dataList.map((String items) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: items,
                            child: Text(items),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            textEditingController.text.value = newValue!;
                          });
                        },
                      ) : Container(),
                  ]
                  )
                },)
```

Comment: can i do it for textfield?

Comment: ummm...i thought you wanted a dropdown though the concept won't change it'll work for anything

Comment: can you show   code textfield insted of dropdown

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by textfield though you can open a dropdown whenever a textfield is click by using onTap method of textfields.

Comment: yes definetly i want to it. can i use that code or you know other solition?

Comment: Once you create a list from firebase then you can pretty much use it for anything

Comment: with what stream or future? for example your code?

Comment: I've edited my answer, though you should explain your ui a bit more it is still unclear to me

Comment: ok i have a form with textfield i want  when user click textfield show firebase collection under that textfield after user can select one it ok. it is look like dropdown but not dropdown coz next step users can search in that textfield

Comment: ummm so shouldn't you use https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search or https://pub.dev/packages/searchable_dropdown this can solve all your problems.

Comment: can i use that with firebase?

Comment: yupps you totally can

Comment: how can i use  searchable dropdown with firebase can you send example code?

Comment: any update? can you give me example with firebase